# Angular2 OnPush change detection and ngFor

Tags: performance, angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a parent component that displays a list of child components using `ngFor`. I noticed that performance gets really bad with increasing number of children so I have changed both to `OnPush` change detection strategy.

That helped a lot, but there are still few scenarios when it slows down and I can see thats due to change detection being executed for each of the children unnecessarily.

One example is when there is a click event inside the child component - even though no inputs is changed and its just triggering an animation, for some reason the change detection is being executed for parent component and as a result for each child component as well (even though the model behind `ngFor` doesnt change at all and its a `OnPush` strategy...). I would have thought that this kind of "isolated" event should only trigger change detection in that particular child component and not propagate up (I have actually tried `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()` with no success).

So I was wondering two things:

1) is there any way of having more control for what events change detection actually runs and whether it triggers the parent component change detecion as well?

2) is using "translate" pipes quite a lot in each child component (from ng2translate) could slow the application/change detection a lot?

Sample plunkr below to show what the problem is. Basically if I click on any of the item in ngFor list, it kicks of change detection for every single child rather than only the affected one and I was wondering if there is any way of suppressing that.

https://plnkr.co/edit/mD8HCbwq0cEwPt7itpCf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can use `ChangeDetectorRef.detach()`

https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html#!#detach-anchor

> Detaches the change detector from the change detector tree.
>
> The detached change detector will not be checked until it is reattached.
>
> This can also be used in combination with ChangeDetectorRef to implement local change detection checks.

2) pipes (if they are pure, which is the default) are only called when piped values or parameters change, therefore there is no performance disadvantage.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question with plunkr to better demonstrate the problem. But basically there is no way to "suppress" sibling change detection and I would need to detach change detection altogether and handle it on my own?

Comment: @Zyga I think there is no change detection in your child components. Put console.log inside `isVisible` method. It will invoke only for your clicked item. https://plnkr.co/edit/v514QJfNYXe13KKh23L2?p=preview `ngDoCheck` is running for all children. If you remove `OnPush` then all your children will be checked

Comment: @Zyga Angular marks `OnPush` component as checked after first change detection cycle and then they will be omitted http://take.ms/ZYOfB

Comment: @Zyga Here is what angular calls change detection http://take.ms/XJhmx. It is view checking.

Comment: @yurzui I thought that once ngDoCheck() is called that means all the bindings for the component are checked (which is what I thought is change detection). console.log in isVisible is not executed because the value didnt change from the last run. That was my understanding, altho I might be wrong :). In my real code with lots of items I can see that executing this ngDoCheck() takes long time actually and causes perf hit, I just thought it shudnt have to do it for all child components when only one of them is clicked? But again maybe I am missing some point here...

Comment: @yurzui I think I know what you mean tho. The change detection mode for OnPush component is set to CheckOne in the first run so its not being checked later on, even tho the ngDoCheck() method is called. I still wonder should that be called tho for all the "siblings" as a result of click event only in one of the children. I assume its because its run in the parent by default and that causes to run for every item in ngFor?

Comment: @Zyga When you use `ngFor` angular internally creates its own changeDetector (not OnPush) for each of your items with context `NgForRow` http://take.ms/g2aqK. Within `detectChangesInternal` of ngForRow changeDetector is executing `ngDoCheck` for your child component http://prntscr.com/e5ky5u

Comment: @yurzui I think thats it then, I might play around and see what happens if i detach change detection and try to handle it myself. thanks for your time on this, please feel free to submit as answer I can accept as it explains why this is happening if anyone else ever run into this problem